# is it possible to get stanger Facebook website likes count with Graph API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Like in title, I am trying to do that but I am getting 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url with every token I was able to generate in facebook dev website.

Is there anything I am missing or just facebook prevents from getting data like this.

Comment: By _"stanger Facebook website"_ you mean a Facebook _page_, that you don't have admin access to? For that to work, your app would need to get the [Page Public Metadata Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-metadata-access) feature approved.